# Change x-axis marks in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, axis, pyqtgraph

I have a graph in an application with pyqt5. The graph is made with pyqtgraph like this:
plotWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
I use it to plot audio signals, but the x-axis marks the labels by default. How can I put other labels different from the ones that pyqtgraph puts?
The following line is the one I use to graph:
elf.curve = self.graphWidget.plot(self.signal)
This is how it shows an audio:
[image]

I need is to change the marks of the x axis

Comment: Please clarify the question and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.

Comment: I've never used `PyQtGraph` but (as much as I can guess from the scarce details you provided) the [docs](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plotting.html) seem to suggest that in order to display the correct x-values you need to provide the optional `x` parameter. I believe you can pass `range(start, stop, step)` with the apropriate `start`, `stop` and `step` (provided that it generates the sequence of the same size as `self.signal`).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@absolute-madness is basically correct; if you don't pass an explicit set of x values to your plot, PyQtGraph will just number them starting at 0. I recommend using [linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) to produce an array with values across a range, but whatever you use will probably work. I *expect* your audio samples have time values for their x coordinate, and if you don't already have that data, what you want is to incorporate your sample rate into that range (and maybe use a [DateAxisItem](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/dateaxisitem.html?highlight=DateAxisItem) to display them, though likely you'll just want to have a 0 time at the start of your graph, rather than a specific date and time). Then just pass the x values into the `.plot(self.time_vals, self.signal)` call.